# Angular 2 Pipe under condition

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, angular-pipe, angular2-pipe

Is it possible in Angular 2 to apply a pipe under condition?
I would like to do something like:

```
{{ variable.text | (variable.value ? SomePipe : OtherPipe) }}
```

If not, what is the preferred way to achieve this effect?

Comment: I think that should work. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it causes template parse errors.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You need to change the syntax a bit:

```
{{variable.value ? (variable.text | SomePipe) : (variable.text | pipe2)}}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zIP2mKbGTthvHQglo0kW?p=preview)

Comment: Can i use this inside ngFor?? ex: `<div *ngFor="let item of data | slice:0:20">`. I need to apply the filter only in some cases

Comment: Sure, can be used in `*ngFor` as well.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer `*ngFor="let a of (condition ? (arr | pipe) : (arr | pipe2))"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi I have a similar problem but instead of custom pipes I want to use the built in ones. I created a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942986/angular-conditional-using-built-in-pipes can you help me?

Comment: I want to apply condition on output of one pipe, and decide another, is it possible

Comment: I think so, but haven't tried. Have you tried? Did it cause an error? What have you tried? What was the error?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use the pipe as a index of a dictionary. I am using constant as index for the dictionary so how can I use that constant as a index in html?

Comment: Very nice Sire!

Comment: Wahnsinn Günter, einfach Wahnsinn! Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 10):

You could also use [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="variable.value; else elseBlock">{{ variable.text | SomePipe }}</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>{{ variable.text | OtherPipe }}</ng-template>
```

I find it useful in case the line becomes too long.

Comment: You can replace the <span> with a <ng-container> so that only the text will be conditional, and no markup will be included in the first case.

Answer (score 8):

As others pointed out, you can use the syntax of `{{condition ? (value | pipe1) : (value2 | pipe2 )}}`.

But it is worth knowing that also the format parameter of a pipe can be dynamic. e.g. this is an example of a number which can be formatted with a high precision or a low precision. The condition is passed to a method, which will create a formatter text conditionally.

```
  // in template
  {{ value | number:getFormat(true) }}

  // in .ts
  public getFormat(highPrecision = false): string {
    const digits = highPrecision ? 3 : 2;
    return `1.${digits}-${digits}`;
  }
```

**So, yes, you can use a condition to select between 2 pipes. But in some cases you may prefer (or only need) to use one pipe with a conditional format parameter.**.

Answer (score 6):

Since such syntax isn't supported, I think that the only way to do that is to implement another pipe to handle the condition:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'condition'
})
export class ConditionPipe {
  transform(val,conditions) {
    let condition = conditions[0];
    let conditionValue = conditions[1];

    if (condition===conditionValue) {
      return new Pipe1().transform(val);
    } else {
      return new Pipe2().transform(val);
    }
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div>
      {{val | condition:cond:1}}<br/>
    </div>
  `,
  pipes: [ Pipe1, Pipe2, ConditionPipe ]
})
export class App {
  val:string = 'test';
  cond:number = 1;
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/KPIA5ly515xZk4QZx4lp?p=preview.

Comment: It's rather a work-around than an actual solution in this case, but may be useful for more complicated cases, +1

Comment: Yes you're right! The Günter's solution is better for simple use cases ;-)

Comment: I think `Pipe1` and `Pipe2` should be injected in `ConditionPipe`'s constructor instead of making a new one. About more complexe usecases, mine is a condition to use uppercase pipe: `isLabelLowerCase ? (label | translate) : (label | translate | uppercase)` => `label | translateWithCase : isLabelLowerCase`, which sounds great