# Angular2 pipes under condition, check type

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I found the way pipe under condition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928435/angular-2-pipe-under-condition)

How can I check the type is number and give it pipes?

```
{{(item).isNumber ? (item | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2') : (item)}}
```

like this.

ps. I'd not like to use custom pipe decoration.

Any good ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use methods and objects that are available from within your component class. So no native Javascript functions are available in the string interpolation.

You can however write a helper method in your component (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421988/1961059)):

```ts
isNumber(o): boolean {
  return ! isNaN (o-0) && o !== null && o !== "" && o !== false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```ts
{{ isNumber(item) ? (item | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2') : (item) }}
```