# Conditionally formatting dates in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a property that I am displaying on an angular template which may or may not be a date. If it is a date, I would like to format it but if it's not, I just want to show the value.

This is what I have tried based on researching and it only worked for dates, for everything else it was blank:

```
<td>{{key | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' || key}}</td>
```

I could add a Boolean property:

```
<td *ngIf="isDate">{{key | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
<td *ngIf="!isDate">{{key}}</td>
```

but is there a way to do this directly in the template?

Comment: The first solution you have posted seems to be working. Do you want something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928435/angular-2-pipe-under-condition

Comment: @MartinoLessio The first solution is not working if the key is not a date

Comment: @Z.Bagley what is the condition I would be checking for?

Comment: on the 2nd condition you need to add another test key | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' || (key && !date or something similar) as no matter what the key is it will always be true and will show up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date

Comment: @cooper are you sure? please look at this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mlessio/dbLk9ab4/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the value on the typescript side first to see (for example) if the value contains a "/" and set another variable to true or false if it is indeed a date or not.