# Angular conditional using built in pipes

Tags: angular

Hi I have a similar problem posted in here: [Angular 2 Pipe under condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928435/angular-2-pipe-under-condition)

But instead of creating custom pipes, I would like to use the built in ones.

Say I have an array like this:

```
[{value: '1', type:'number'},{value:'1/18/2018', type: 'date'}]
```

and would like to use it like this assuming I'm looping through it:

```
{{ arr.type ? (arr.value | arr.type) : (arr.value)}}
```

It gives me an error of `Parser Error: Missing expected )`

Comment: What if you do `| [arr.type]`? If that also doesn't work you can always use the pipes in the definition itself by injecting the pipe into constructor of the class in which the definition exists.

Comment: arr,type ? (arr.type === 'number' ? (arr.value | number) : (arr.value | date) ) : arr.value

Comment: @Chrillewoodz it didnt work. For the latter solution I dont know if I understand you correctly but what I did is imported the pipes to my class then defined it in constructor and made my array like this. [{value: '1', type:this.decimalPipe},{value:'1/18/2018', type: this.datePipe}] but still did not work. I still get template errors.

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi I've also  thought about that solution but what if I have to use more built in pipes, then I would have a long ternary statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public myArr = [this.numberPipe(1), this.datePipe('1/18/2018', 'yyyy-MM-dd')];

constructor(private numberPipe: NumberPipe, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

And then in template simply loop the values and display it with `{{arr}}`.

Comment: Actually I am using primeng table here https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sections do you know how I will implement it using primeng?

Comment: I mean in the link I mentioned, myArr is only the equivalent of the cols array. It only contains the column headers and field names not the actual values which is what is illustrated in your example.

Comment: That's outside of the scope of your question. Your current question is about how to use the pipes to get the correct values. If you need further help I suggest opening a new question that targets the other issue.

Comment: I've opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944629/angular-primeng-table-set-up-pipe-per-column-using-cols-array. Will you help me out? Thanks.