# Angular PrimeNG table set up pipe per column using cols array

Tags: angular, primeng-turbotable

I am trying to learn angular with PrimeNG. Here is the link https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table.

Is it possible to also include the pipe for each column using the pipe array?

In the cols array, I would like to add another field like this.

```
this.cols = [
    { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', type: 'date' },
    { field: 'year', header: 'Year', type: 'number' },
    { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', type: 'number' },
    { field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
];
```

And then in the template, I would use it like this

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{ col.type? rowData[col.field] | col.type : rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried this and it gives me template parsing errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to do following:

1. In your ts file import pipes that you need:

   ```
   import { 
     CurrencyPipe,
     LowerCasePipe,
     UpperCasePipe
   } from '@angular/common';
   ```
2. Add them to providers property of your component

   ```
   providers: [
     CurrencyPipe, 
     LowerCasePipe,
     UpperCasePipe
   ]
   ```
3. Pass pipes via constructor as `private`

   ```
   constructor(private cp: CurrencyPipe, 
               private lcp: LowerCasePipe,
               private ucp: UpperCasePipe) {
   }
   ```
4. Pass pipes to your HTML via `cols`:

   ```
   this.cols = [
     { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', type: this.ucp },
     { field: 'startYear', header: 'Year', type: this.cp, arg1: 'CAD'},
     { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', type: this.lcp },
     { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
   ];
   ```

   I did not find a nice way to pass an array of args to HTML (`pipe(val, ...args)` will not work in HTML), so I added `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`, which we can pass and use.
5. Consume it in your HTML:

   ```
   <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
     {{ col.type ? col.type.transform(rowData[col.field], col.arg1, col.arg2, col.arg3) : rowData[col.field] }}
   </td>
   ```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4x6q9b?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts