# Is it possible to apply a conditional pipe which itself contains a condition?

Tags: angular, pipe, conditional-statements, angular7, angular-material-7

I have a dropdown (input + autocomplete) where I can type a string or select an object from the dropdown list.
I want to use the pipe only when the value in the input is of type string. If user selects a value from dropdown, I need to remove the custom pipe.

I want to apply the custom pipe the typeof option.name is String. and to remove it if type is Object.

Tried the link, but in vain 
[Angular 2 Pipe under condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928435/angular-2-pipe-under-condition)

Actual code:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of sortedOptions"
       [innerHTML]="option?.name | highlight : userControl.value" >
```

What I am not able to understand is how to check String type here:

```
{{ typeof(option.name) ? (option?.name | highlight : userControl.value)  : option.name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper method on your component like this:

```
isString(val) { return typeof val === 'string'; }
```

Now you can check your condition like this:

```
{{ isString(option.name) ? (option?.name | highlight : userControl.value)  : option.name }}
```

**Here is the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m75cgf?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you**

Comment: Thank you for showing the way. but  Its not highlighting when the type is String.

Comment: @MissKomal I updated my answer and added a stackblitz demo, see it in action there