# using custom pipe with ternary operator for *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am using custom pipe with ternary operator for `*ngFor`, getting errors. Not knowing how to resolve. Please kindly help.

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y | limitTo: y.limit ? y.length : 10">
```

truncate.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'limitTo'
})
export class TruncatePipe {
  transform(value: string, limit:number) : string {
    let trail = '...';

    return value.length > limit ? limit + trail : value;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import {  TruncatePipe }   from './truncate.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
  ],
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
  ],
  exports: [ 
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '10...' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`. in html file

Comment: refer this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928435/angular-2-pipe-under-condition

Comment: @Dixit Savaliya pipe is not working for *ngFor.

Comment: add parenthesis, Angular think that the last ":" are a new parameter of the pipe `"let x of y | limitTo: (y.limit ? y.length : 10)"`

Comment: *ngFor doesn't work with strings. You should use array in *ngFor e. g. https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz, what is `y`?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing string to the ngFor which is not accepted. make sure you pass the array. i.e "x" should be array

Comment: if that so, then removing my custom pipe , *ngFor should not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing whole array to your pipe. 
If length is higher lower than the limit it will return array unchanged. 
Otherwise it will return array length followed by trail.

You most likely have an array `y = ['str-1', 'str-2', 'str-3'...]`
Your pipe call is `limitTo: y.limit ? y.length : 10`
If itterable y doesn't have limit field or if it's 0 it will default to 10.

In your question pipe was called with arguments value = y and limit = 10
Trail is '...';

If length of array y is lower than limit (in this example 10, which is false)
it would end up returning the array unchanged.

Otherwise it will return `limit + trail` which equals 10 + '...'.
This is a string.

Strings are not iterable and therefore you will receive an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what is desired result. I will try to help you out with that if you would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all

Solution Worked:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of (y.limit ? (y | slice: 0 : y.length) : (y | slice: 0 : 10))">
```